# Markdown mode codemirror creating

Tags: javascript, regex, browser, mode, codemirror

anyone can help me to create new mode to codemirror?

I need to put this part `{>1<}` of `{>1<}![title](site)` invisible (into span with specific class)

How I can do that?

I tryed something like that:

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("imageID", {
    start: [
       {regex: /(?:\{\>([^<]*)\<\})/gmi, token: "imageID"}
    ]
});
```

but it doesn't work... any ideas why?

Comment: CodeMirror modes can not make text invisible. You'll have to use the `markText` method for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
function findNext(lastPos){
    var text = /^\!\[([^\]]*)\]\(([^\)]*)\)+/;
    for (cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text); cursor.findNext();)
        editor.replaceRange('{>'+(i++)+'<}',cursor.from(),cursor.from())
        cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text, lastPos || editor.getCursor()); 
if (!cursor.findNext()){ 
   cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text); 
    if (!cursor.findNext()) {return;}
}
    lastPos = cursor.to();
}

//------------------------------------

function findAloneIdx(lastPos){

    var text = /(\{\>([^<]*)\<\}\!?\[?)+/;
    for (cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text); cursor.findNext();)
        if(editor.getRange(cursor.from(), cursor.to()).slice(-2) !== '![')
            editor.replaceRange('',cursor.from(),cursor.to())
        else
            editor.markText(cursor.from(), {line: cursor.to().line, ch:   cursor.to().ch-2}, {className: "styled-background"});
            cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text, lastPos || editor.getCursor()); 
    if (!cursor.findNext()){ 
       cursor = editor.getSearchCursor(text); 
       if (!cursor.findNext()) {return;}
    }
    lastPos = cursor.to();
}
```